# Потоки замедляют работу друг друга, что делать?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Написал алгоритм поиска по мотивам расстояния Левенштейна для проекта универского, собственно поиск работает не достаточно быстро как требуется, поэтому попытался использовать потоки. Моя идея заключалась в том, чтоб обрабатывать часть слов, по которым ведётся поиск, в одном потоке, другую часть во втором потоке и так далее. Но когда я прописал собственно всё это дело и начал измерять время работы, я обнаружил интересность:
Допустим я ввожу 4-ёх буквенный запрос и пытаюсь замерять время после `join()` для каждого потока. Получаю в своём случае вот такие числа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше я опишу как именно я выделяю потоки и работаю с ними, а сейчас предположим, что мы просто увидели время работы 7 потоков. А теперь делаем тоже самое, но запускаем лишь один поток(то есть проводим поиск на 1/7 от всего списка слов), получаем такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для меня такой результат искренне не понятен. В моей системе стоит 8 ядерный 16 поточный камень, поэтому ему явно хватает возможностей запускать все эти потоки параллельно. Но в данном случае явно видно, что один поток работает в 3-4 раза быстрее, чем он же, но одновременно с другими шестью. Сколько не искал, ничего полезного не нашёл. Потоки используют лишь один общий вектор, но даже если убрать строчку с его использованием - проблема останется. Поэтому проблем с *гонкой данных* вроде как нет.

Теперь сам кусок кода с потоками:

```
#ifdef LEVENSTAINSEARCHTIME_DEBUG
    auto start = chrono::system_clock::now();
#endif // LEVENSTAINSEARCHTIME_DEBUG
    vector<thread> workers;
    vector<pair<string, int>> tag_list;
    vector<vector<Points>> points_list((tags_.size() / WORDSPERTHREAD) + 1);//points_list хранит вектор Points от каждого потока\
    заранее выделяем под него память
    int cur_count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < tags_.size(); i++)
    {
        //tags_ - контейнер, хранящий теги, по которым ведётся поиск
        if (tags_[i].type != type && type != TagsField::TYPELIST::pANY &&
            type != TagsField::TYPELIST::pANYWITHSPECIALIZATION)//тип тегов, по которым мы ищем
            continue;
        tag_list.push_back({ tags_[i].name,i });//часть списка тегов, которая будет передаваться каждому потоку 
        if (tag_list.size() != WORDSPERTHREAD && i != tags_.size() - 1) // WORDSPERTHREAD констатное выражение, показывающее сколько слов\
            будет лежать в каждом потоке
            continue;
        if (tag_list.empty())
            continue;
        workers.push_back(thread([](vector<string> request_list, vector<pair<string, int>> tag_list,
            vector<Points>& points) -> void
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < tag_list.size(); k++)
                {
                    double min_cur_dist = MAXINT;
                    for (int j = 0; j < request_list.size(); j++)//request_list - вектор строк, хранящий строки запроса без пробелов
                    {
                        if (request_list[j].empty())
                            continue;
                        //double cur_dist = 0;
                        double cur_dist = GetRange(request_list[j], tag_list[k].first);//сама функция поиска
                        if (min_cur_dist > cur_dist)
                            min_cur_dist = cur_dist;//если нашли слово в запросе, более похожее на тег, то обновляем переменную
                    }
                    if (min_cur_dist < MAXINT)//тут отражаем сходимость k-го тега с каким-то словом из запроса
                    {
                        points.push_back(Points(tag_list[k].second, 0, min_cur_dist));//закидываем в наш контейнер результат работы потока
                    }
                }
            }, request_list, tag_list, ref(points_list[cur_count])));//points_list хранит вектор Points от каждого потока\
        cur_count говорит о текущем номере потока
        cur_count++;
        tag_list.clear();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < workers.size(); i++)
    {
        workers[i].join();//ожидаем пока все потоки справятся с работой

#ifdef LEVENSTAINSEARCHTIME_DEBUG//просто выводим время работы
        auto end = chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto dur = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
        cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << (double)dur.count() / 1000000 << 's' << endl;
#endif // LEVENSTAINSEARCHTIME_DEBUG
    }
```

Собственно весь алгоритм.

Также прикрепляю алгоритм поиска `GetRange`

```
constexpr int delete_cost = 2;
constexpr int swap_cost = 1;
constexpr int add_cost = 2;
constexpr int transposition_cost = 2;
constexpr int magic_coefficient = 100;

map<int, vector<int>> distance_code_key
{
    /* '`' */ { 192 , { 49 }},
    /* '1' */ { 49 , { 50, 87, 81 }},
    /* '2' */ { 50 , { 49, 81, 87, 69, 51 }},
    /* '3' */ { 51 , { 50, 87, 69, 82, 52 }},
    /* '4' */ { 52 , { 51, 69, 82, 84, 53 }},
    /* '5' */ { 53 , { 52, 82, 84, 89, 54 }},
    /* '6' */ { 54 , { 53, 84, 89, 85, 55 }},
    /* '7' */ { 55 , { 54, 89, 85, 73, 56 }},
    /* '8' */ { 56 , { 55, 85, 73, 79, 57 }},
    /* '9' */ { 57 , { 56, 73, 79, 80, 48 }},
    /* '0' */ { 48 , { 57, 79, 80, 219, 189 }},
    /* '-' */ { 189 , { 48, 80, 219, 221, 187 }},
    /* '+' */ { 187 , { 189, 219, 221 }},
    /* 'q' */ { 81 , { 49, 50, 87, 83, 65 }},
    /* 'w' */ { 87 , { 49, 81, 65, 83, 68, 69, 51, 50 }},
    /* 'e' */ { 69 , { 50, 87, 83, 68, 70, 82, 52, 51 }},
    /* 'r' */ { 82 , { 51, 69, 68, 70, 71, 84, 53, 52 }},
    /* 't' */ { 84 , { 52, 82, 70, 71, 72, 89, 54, 53 }},
    /* 'y' */ { 89 , { 53, 84, 71, 72, 74, 85, 55, 54 }},
    /* 'u' */ { 85 , { 54, 89, 72, 74, 75, 73, 56, 55 }},
    /* 'i' */ { 73 , { 55, 85, 74, 75, 76, 79, 57, 56 }},
    /* 'o' */ { 79 , { 56, 73, 75, 76, 186, 80, 48, 57 }},
    /* 'p' */ { 80 , { 57, 79, 76, 186, 222, 219, 189, 48 }},
    /* '[' */ { 219 , { 48, 186, 222, 221, 187, 189 }},
    /* ']' */ { 221 , { 189, 219, 187 }},
    /* 'a' */ { 65 , { 81, 87, 83, 88, 90 }},
    /* 's' */ { 83 , { 81, 65, 90, 88, 67, 68, 69, 87, 81 }},
    /* 'd' */ { 68 , { 87, 83, 88, 67, 86, 70, 82, 69 }},
    /* 'f' */ { 70 , { 69, 68, 67, 86, 66, 71, 84, 82 }},
    /* 'g' */ { 71 , { 82, 70, 86, 66, 78, 72, 89, 84 }},
    /* 'h' */ { 72 , { 84, 71, 66, 78, 77, 74, 85, 89 }},
    /* 'j' */ { 74 , { 89, 72, 78, 77, 188, 75, 73, 85 }},
    /* 'k' */ { 75 , { 85, 74, 77, 188, 190, 76, 79, 73 }},
    /* 'l' */ { 76 , { 73, 75, 188, 190, 191, 186, 80, 79 }},
    /* ';' */ { 186 , { 79, 76, 190, 191, 222, 219, 80 }},
    /* '\''*/ { 222 , { 80, 186, 191, 221, 219 }},
    /* 'z' */ { 90 , { 65, 83, 88 }},
    /* 'x' */ { 88 , { 90, 65, 83, 68, 67 }},
    /* 'c' */ { 67 , { 88, 83, 68, 70, 86 }},
    /* 'v' */ { 86 , { 67, 68, 70, 71, 66 }},
    /* 'b' */ { 66 , { 86, 70, 71, 72, 78 }},
    /* 'n' */ { 78 , { 66, 71, 72, 74, 77 }},
    /* 'm' */ { 77 , { 78, 72, 74, 75, 188 }},
    /* '<' */ { 188 , { 77, 74, 75, 76, 190 }},
    /* '>' */ { 190 , { 188, 75, 76, 186, 191 }},
    /* '?' */ { 191 , { 190, 76, 186, 222 }},
};
map<char, int> code_keys_eng
{
        { '`', 192 },
        { '1', 49   },
        { '2', 50   },
        { '3', 51   },
        { '4', 52   },
        { '5', 53   },
        { '6', 54   },
        { '7', 55   },
        { '8', 56   },
        { '9', 57   },
        { '0', 48   },
        { '-', 189  },
        { '=', 187  },
        { 'q', 81   },
        { 'w', 87   },
        { 'e', 69   },
        { 'r', 82   },
        { 't', 84   },
        { 'y', 89   },
        { 'u', 85   },
        { 'i', 73   },
        { 'o', 79   },
        { 'p', 80   },
        { '[', 219  },
        { ']', 221  },
        { 'a', 65   },
        { 's', 83   },
        { 'd', 68   },
        { 'f', 70   },
        { 'g', 71   },
        { 'h', 72   },
        { 'j', 74   },
        { 'k', 75   },
        { 'l', 76   },
        { ';', 186  },
        { '\'', 222 },
        { 'z', 90   },
        { 'x', 88   },
        { 'c', 67   },
        { 'v', 86   },
        { 'b', 66   },
        { 'n', 78   },
        { 'm', 77   },
        { ',', 188  },
        { '.', 190  },
        { '/', 191  },

        { '~' , 192 },
        { '!' , 49  },
        { '@' , 50  },
        { '#' , 51  },
        { '$' , 52  },
        { '%' , 53  },
        { '^' , 54  },
        { '&' , 55  },
        { '*' , 56  },
        { '(' , 57  },
        { ')' , 48  },
        { '_' , 189 },
        { '+' , 187 },

        { '{', 219  },
        { '}', 221  },
        { ':', 186  },
        { '"', 222  },

        { '<', 188  },
        { '>', 190  },
        { '?', 191  },
};
vector<string> phonetic_groups
{
    { "aeiouy", "bp", "ckq", "dt", "lr", "mn", "gj", "fpv", "sxz", "csz" }
};


size_t CostDistanceSymbol(const char& source_symbol, const char& target_symbol)
{
    if (source_symbol == target_symbol)
        return 0;
    size_t distance_cost = 2;
    if (distance_code_key[code_keys_eng[source_symbol]].empty())
        distance_cost = 2;
    vector<int> list = distance_code_key[code_keys_eng[source_symbol]];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        if (list[i] == code_keys_eng[target_symbol])
        {
            distance_cost = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    size_t phonetic_cost = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < phonetic_groups.size(); i++)
    {
        if (phonetic_groups[i].find(source_symbol) != -1 && phonetic_groups[i].find(target_symbol) != -1)
        {
            phonetic_cost = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return min(distance_cost, phonetic_cost);
}

size_t LevenstainDistanceUpgrade(const string& source, const string& target)
{
    if (source.empty())
    {
        return target.size() * add_cost;
    }
    int N = source.size(), M = target.size();
    vector<vector<int>> Dist(N + 1, vector<int>(M + 1, 0));
    for (int j = 1; j <= M; j++)
    {
        Dist[0][j] = Dist[0][j - 1] + add_cost;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        Dist[i][0] = Dist[i - 1][0] + delete_cost;
        for (int j = 1; j <= M; j++)
        {
            //int cur_swap_cost = CostDistanceSymbol(source[i], target[j]);
            int cur_swap_cost = (RegisterMerge(source[i - 1]) == RegisterMerge(target[j - 1]) ? 0 : swap_cost);
            Dist[i][j] = min(Dist[i - 1][j] + delete_cost,
                min(Dist[i][j - 1] + add_cost, Dist[i - 1][j - 1] + cur_swap_cost));
            if (i > 1 && j > 1)
            {
                if (RegisterMerge(source[i]) == RegisterMerge(target[j - 1]) && RegisterMerge(source[i - 1]) == RegisterMerge(target[j]))
                    Dist[i][j] = min(Dist[i][j], Dist[i - 2][j - 2] + transposition_cost);
            }
        }
    }
    return Dist[N][M];
}

double GetRangeWord(const string& source, const string& target)
{
    double word_distance = MAXINT;
    int length = min(source.size() + 1, target.size());
    for (int i = 0; i <= target.size() - length; i++)
    {
        string cropped_target = target.substr(i, length);
        word_distance = min((LevenstainDistanceUpgrade(source, cropped_target) + (i * 2 / 10.0)), word_distance);
    }
    return word_distance;
}

double GetRange(const string& source, const string& target)
{
    if (source.size() <= 3)//в этом случае просто наивные вхождения смотрим
    {
        int pos = RegisterStrMerge(target).find(RegisterStrMerge(source));
        if (pos != -1)
            return (pos * 2 / 10.0);
        else
            return MAXINT;
    }
    vector<string> source_word_list = GetList(source, ' ');
    vector<string> target_word_list = GetList(target, ' ');
    if (source_word_list.empty())
    {
        int distance = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < target_word_list.size(); i++)
        {
            distance += (target_word_list[i].size() * add_cost * magic_coefficient);
        }
    }
    double distance = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < source_word_list.size(); i++)
    {
        double min_word_distance = MAXINT;
        int min_pos = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < target_word_list.size(); j++)
        {
            double cur_word_distance = GetRangeWord(source_word_list[i], target_word_list[j]);
            if (cur_word_distance < min_word_distance)
            {
                min_word_distance = cur_word_distance;
                min_pos = j;
            }
        }
        distance += (min_word_distance * magic_coefficient + abs(i - min_pos) / 10.0);
    }
    return distance;
}
```

Общие данные вначале (2 вектора и мапа) в алгоритме отключены.

Comment: вы нагружаете систему выделением памяти в семь раз больше. всё из-за четырнадцати копий одинаковых векторов. `[](vector<string> request_list, vector<pair<string, int>> tag_list,` попробуйте передавать хотя-бы константными ссылками `const &`.

Comment: а почему не просто ссылкой? Или константная ссылка чем-то лучше будет( ну кроме того, что объект гарантировано нельзя будет изменять в теле функции)?

Comment: а, и ссылку нельзя передавать, ибо после инициализации потока, вектор ```tag_list``` очищается... Поэтому программа выдаст "vector out of range" при попытке обратиться к этому контейнеру внутри потока...

Comment: И проблем с памятью у меня нет, моя главное проблема - время работы одного потока, когда одновременно с ним запущены ещё несколько. И моя цель решить именно эту проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте переписать на чистый Си и вызовы posix threads (это те функции, которые начинаются с `pthread_`). / Глядишь, и все ошибки сами вылезут на свет

Comment: Тогда ведь я не смогу использовать вектора и мапы, которые используются у меня в самом алгоритме поиска ```GetRange```. Не совсем понимаю, что вы подразумеваете под "Все ошибки сами вылезут". Ведь тут же дело в некотором недопонимание работы механизма потоков. Сам алгоритм то работает.

Comment: @МаксимГерасимов, как известно, "дьявол в деталях". Где-то в реализации этих векторов и мапов. Чтобы получить эффективную программу вы должны *полностью контролировать код*. На Си это значительно проще, чем на С++ (который, как говорят, хорош для экономики, он создает дополнительные рабочие места)

Comment: Я не вижу как вы измеряете время. Запуск потока судя по всему входит в это? Надо бы исключить для честного сравнения

Comment: Я проверял отдельно время, уходящее на запуск потока, оно составляет сотые секунды для всех в сумме, так что им можно пренебречь

Comment: @avp, попробую полностью переписать на СИ, отпишусь после этого сразу(правда я думаю, что на это мне понадобиться кучу времени)

Comment: `проблем с памятью у меня нет` - как вы проверили, что проблема не в том, что у вас больше операций выделения памяти для случая с 7-ю потоками?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что памяти мне хватает, даже если я её выделяю избыточно много. Моя главная задача именно в оптимизации времени работы. Или вы имеете ввиду, что из-за выделения памяти как раз и происходит такое увеличение времени работы?

Comment: @avp, я правильно понимаю, что в ```stl``` контейнерах присутствует некоторая реализация ```mutex```, которая и замедляет работу алгоритма?

Comment: По итогу я написал алгоритм на СИ,  получилось ускорить всё это дело. Но я всё ещё не понимаю, почему предыдущий вариант тормозился, ведь вектора и мапы в качестве общих данных использовались лишь в одном месте, которое, как я и говорил, я пробовал закомментировать и это не дало результата

Comment: @МаксимГерасимов, я не знаю это mutex-ы (надо смотреть сорсы) или такое распределение памяти, которое плохо ложится в кэши процессора. Но результат вы увидели и общую идею о применимости языков, надеюсь, уловили

Comment: Звучит так, что про ```stl``` вообще лучше забыть...